# Unexpected behaviour by elasticsearch "query_string" for different fields having same mapping

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch version 6.3.1 for a django project. I am using regular expressions supported by query_string filter but two of my fields in same index have same mapping although while searching with spaces, one key is returning values and other is not.

As both of my fields have strings stored in them so I have tried with both keyword and full-text search with query_string.

**Mappings -**

Field 1 -

```py
{u'field1': {u'full_name': u'field1',
     u'mapping': {u'field1': {u'fields': {u'keyword': {u'ignore_above': 256,
         u'type': u'keyword'}},
       u'type': u'text'}}},
```

Field 2 -

```
    {u'field2': {u'full_name': u'field2',
     u'mapping': {u'field2': {u'fields': {u'keyword': {u'ignore_above': 256,
         u'type': u'keyword'}},
       u'type': u'text'}}}}}}}
```

**Value stored in both fields -**

Field 1 - 
"test abc"

Field 2 -
"test test abc test abc"

**Query**

For field2 -

```
{'_source': 'field1',
 'from': 0,
 'query': {'bool': {
    'must': [
        {'term': {'field3.keyword':'Test1'}},
        {'term': {'field4': 1741}},
        {'query_string': {
            'fields': ['field2.keyword'],
            'query': '/.*test abc.*/',
            }
        }
        ],
  }}]}},
 'size': 50}
```

For field1 -

```
{'_source': 'field1',
 'from': 0,
 'query': {'bool': {
    'must': [
        {'term': {'field3.keyword':'Test1'}},
        {'term': {'field4': 1741}},
        {'query_string': {
            'fields': ['field1.keyword'],
            'query': '/.*test abc.*/',
            }
        }
        ],
  }}]}},
 'size': 50}
```

Output for field1 -

```
{u'hits': [{u'_id': u'1',
   u'_index': u'test',
   u'_score': 8.594198,
   u'_source': {u'alias': u'test abc'},
   u'_type': u'test'}],
 u'max_score': 8.594198,
 u'total': 1}
```

Output for field2 -

```
{u'hits': [], u'max_score': None, u'total': 0}
```

What could be possible reason for this behaviour?